# Programmatically check if a Windows Server 2008 Feature is installed, and Install it

Tags: installation, script, windows-server-2008-r2

I'd like to be able to detect in a script whether a Windows Server 2008 installation has specific Windows features enabled, and install them if necessary.  I do not simply want to use a "try to install the feature, even if it is already installed" approach, as I need to be able to perform additional steps at the install time.

For example, I know I can install the SNMP Service using the command line:

`pkgmgr /iu:SNMP`

What I don't know is how to check whether this package has been installed, ideally from VBScript/WMI, but from a command-line tool if necessary.

Ideally I also want to find a solution that does not involve Powershell, as I don't want to have to lower the powershell execution privileges that are set by default in a Windows 2008 install.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that you can do this easily with a powershell script (run as administrator).

Here is an example powershell script found on the [internet](http://poshcode.org/2066):

```
#Powershell Script To Install SNMP Services
Import-Module ServerManager
#Check If SNMP Services Are Already Installed
$check = Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "SNMP-Services"}
If ($check.Installed -ne "True") {
        #Install/Enable SNMP Services
        Add-WindowsFeature SNMP-Services | Out-Null
}
```

You can find more information about finding out a feature's name in:
[Windows Server 2008 R2: Adding Features via PowerShell](http://sqlha.com/blog/post/2009/08/17/Windows-Server-2008-R2-Adding-Features-via-PowerShell.aspx)

If WMIC is an option, see these articles:
[New Server Core Tips](http://blogs.technet.com/b/server_core/archive/2008/01/29/new-server-core-tips.aspx)
[Using the new Windows Server 2008 Core OCList and OCSetup CLI tools to Add & Remove Server Roles](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Windows-Server-2008-Core-OCList-OCSetup-CLI-tools-Add-Remove-Server-Roles.html)

If programming is an option, see this stackoverflow article:
[How can I programmatically check if a server feature is installed in Windows Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632241/how-can-i-programmatically-check-if-a-server-feature-is-installed-in-windows-serv)

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured out this method too, but I'm trying to do this without Powershell (this script is intended to be run as part of an OS installation, and I don't want to change the PowerShell default security settings, which prevent powershell scripts from being executed).

Comment: @Richard: See my edit.

Comment: The programming option using WMI was exactly what I was looking for - thanks.  I'd looked at WMI classes, but hadn't found the WMI_ServerFeature class

Answer (score 1):

The suggested answer can actually be simplified a little bit:

```
$check = get-windowsfeature -name SNMP-Services
if ($check.Installed -ne "True") {
        #Install/Enable SNMP Services
        Add-WindowsFeature SNMP-Services | Out-Null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a powershell command that works perfectly. It installs SNMP Services (SNMP Service + SNMP WMI Provider)

```
Servermanagercmd –install SNMP-Services
```